# Cutting off master branch history and start from "nothing" in git

Tags: git

we absorb a project from another company and it's git repo. We only have this one repo and also want to keep the history of the old project.

We started developing in a new branch and now I want to have the master branch "cleaned" and cut off.

Is there a workflow especially for that or is it enough to make a merge? But I think, that if I just merge, some files will be left.

Comment: What do you mean by cleaned and cut off?

Comment: I think we need to know more about what your desired end result is.

Comment: Hello Aaron. I mean that I can see something like a "cut" or a mark, that the master branch is clear/no files are in it. I'm stuck but maybe the solution is just `git rm -rf *`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a truly clean start, you could do the following:

```
git checkout -b oldbranch
git push -u origin oldbranch
git branch -d master
git push origin --delete master
rm -rf *
git checkout --orphan master
# Make some commits
git push -u origin master
```

This creates a new *orphaned* master which has zero commits (not even a root commit), and preserves the old branch as `oldbranch`. The new master branch is entirely free of history and thus serves as a totally separate line of history. This is ideal when the new history will have little to nothing to do with the old history.

Comment: Okay, but here I also need to remove the master branch on the remote

Comment: For some reason, I'm not able to remove the master branch on the remote. But I think that's because of my host.